# Naive Bayes model from scikit learn

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, prediction, naivebayes

What is the difference between the two gnb.fit()?

```
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
gnb = GaussianNB()
gnb.fit(X_train, y_train.ravel())

gnb.fit(X_train, y_train).predict(X_test)
```

Answer (score 0):

I see two differences:

1. `np.ravel` [flattens arrays](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html), e.g.

```
x = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])

np.ravel(x)
array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
```

2. `gnb.fit` returns the model itself, and it can be used to immediately `predict`. Predicting does not modify the model.

If your `y_train` is one-dimensional, you'll get the same model regardless of whether you call `gbn.fit(x, y)` or `gbn.fit(x, y.ravel())` because `y == y.ravel()`